# Proving injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

$T(x,y,z) = (xy, yz, xz) \\
R^3 \rightarrow R^3$

My attempt to try showing surjectivity:

$xy = a \\
yz = b \\
xz = c$

I want to get $x, y,$ and $z$ in terms of $a, b, c.$ So first I try $x = \frac{a}{y}$ then substitute: $\frac{za}{y} = c => y = \frac{za}{c}$ and substitute again: $\frac{z^2 a}{c} = b.$ but then I get stuck here and cannot seem to isolate anything in terms of $a, b,$ and $c$.

Injective:

$xy = x'y' \\
yz = y'z' \\
xz = x'z'$

I have similar algebraic issues here. I try:

$xyz = zx'y' \\
xyz = xy'z' \\
xyz = yx'z'$

So $zx'y' = xy'z' = yx'z'$ but after wasting a lot of paper, I can't get anything to cancel out so I can get each of the letter pairs by themselves (I want $x = x'$, $y = y'$, $z = z'$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not surjective, because if $T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ then
$$abc=(xy)(yz)(xz)=(xyz)^2\ge0\ .$$
Therefore, for example, $T(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1)$ is impossible.

The function is not injective since, for example, $T(1,2,3)=T(-1,-2,-3)$.

---

However, if the domain and codomain were supposed to be triples of *strictly positive* numbers then we have
$$\eqalign{T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)\quad
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad a=xy,\ b=yz,\,c=xz\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x^2=\frac{(xy)(xz)}{yz}=\frac{ac}{b}\quad\hbox{etc}\cr
  &\Leftrightarrow\quad x=\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}},\,y=\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}},\,
    z=\sqrt{\frac{bc}{a}}\ .\cr}$$
Therefore $T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ has a unique positive solution $(x,y,z)$ for every positive triple $(a,b,c)$.  So in this case $T$ would be both injective and surjective.